# jQuery if div is in x position, then reveal another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a div that is moveable in all directions with the keyboard arrows.

I'm trying to make it so that when the moveable div 'walks' down the page and reaches a certain point, another div with text in it appears.

How do I make it so that when the character reaches a certain point on the page, a div dialogue shows?

```
if($('#'+character).position().top > -500) {

    if(character == 'character1') {
       $('#page2 .dialogue').fadeIn(4000);

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have a question because you're posting on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), yet I don't see a question mark anywhere in your text.

Comment: can you provide the demo for the work you have done so far on `jsfiddle.net`? And clearly state the goal, please.

Answer (score 0):

So [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/)() is relative to the containing element while offset() is relative to the document.  With that said, you are asking when an element is 500 **above** the containing div.  You may not be able to see it.  Try removing the **negative** sign.

If you provide a jsfiddle then we can confirm and provide better help.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can set element.style.top but you cannot read it. You need to use element.offsetTop instead, which will give you the position of your div. I'll assume character is a variable which has been defined in advance and is the ID of the div layer.

```
if(document.getElementById(character).offsetTop > 500) {

    if(character == 'character1') {
       $('#page2 .dialogue').fadeIn(4000);

    }
}
```

Oughta do the trick. Call it occasionally to keep checking.
Or even better yet, don't bother with any of that. Keep the character's position in a variable, then set their position that way, and when you need to read the coordinates of the character just read the variable. That's how I'd approach it.